# To find number of onto functions with one local maximum and one local minimum.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Let $f$ be a function defined from $A$ to $A$, where $A=\{1,2, \ldots,10\}$. The discrete points on the graph of $f(x)$ are joined with line segments. Then find the total number of onto functions, which has one local maximum and one local minimum.

Attempt: I tried to think with $10$ into square grid with diagonal $y=x$. But then number of cases are showing no pattern.

Comment: could you give an example of such a function?

Comment: no idea. is the question even correct.

Comment: Are $(1)$ and $(10)$ count as a local maximum/minimum?

Comment: It seems to me that if you allow boundary points i.e. $1$ and $10$ to be local extremas then the function $f(x)=x$ will be an example. There will not be any other functions (as the function must decrease and then increase or increase and then decrease at least once).

Comment: @SumanChakraborty The other function is $11-x$. Hence altogether there are two functions unless the extrema at 1 and 10 are not treated as local.

Comment: @user You are right, two functions in total then, my bad, thanks! (although now it seems that the op is asking at least one extrema)

Comment: @SumanChakraborty I don't understand why OP does not respond to the questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly two functions which satisfy this: The strictly increasing and the strictly decreasing.

There are $10!$ onto functions from $A$ to $A$, as such a function is a permutation of $A$, and any permutation of $A$ defines such a function.  For such functions $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$.  Therefore, $f(x) \neq f(x+1)$, and at $x=1$ and $x=10$ there will be either a local maxima or local minima.  Consequently, to satisfy the stated condition, $f$ cannot have any local maxima or minima except at 1 and 10, and must therefore be either strictly increasing (implying $f(1) = 1$) or strictly decreasing (implying $f(1) = 10$).